# ios multitasking keyboard issue

Tags: uikeyboard, multitasking, uiwindow, split-screen-multitasking

i implemented a custom component which will popup a radial shortcut with overlapping on keyboard.

it works fine if i use application without multitasking(screen sharing) please see below screen shot[image]

but when i run my app with multitasking component go behind keyboard like below image
[image]

but when i again goes in full screen it all start working fine..

Please let me know what to do with such problem.

UIWindow *lastWindow = (UIWindow *)[windows lastObject];
    window.windowLevel = lastWindow.windowLevel + 1;

above code is already used,  please let me know if any way around to increase custom uiwindow rendering priority.

Comment: have you found any answer to the question

Comment: nope didn't get answer for the same.